# Изменение CSS свойств другого дива/элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет!

У меня, как я считаю, банальная проблема, но, видимо, я устал очень. Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на картинку выезжал блок, у которого в свойствах `display: none;`

Я написал следующий код:

```
    $(document).ready( function(){

    var videoItem = $('#videoName a img');
    var videoDescr = $('#videoDescr');

    videoItem.mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.7,
        },200),

        videoDescr.css('display','block').animate({
            left: 120
        });

    }), $(videoItem).mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1,
        },200),

        videoDescr.css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Дело в том, что `display: block` вызывается для одного первого `videoDescr`, а мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на разные картинки выезжали соответствующие им, скрытые блоки. Я не пойму, как правильно сделать выборку и указать `this`, чтобы скрытый блок выезжал для каждой картинки свой. Либо я что-то не так понимаю? Помогите пож. Устал уже.

HTML

```
    <div class="videoName">
         <a href="#" title="Название видео" alt="Название видео">
           <img src="/img/video/1.gif" title="Название видео" alt="Название видео" />
     </a>

    <div class="videoDescr">
           <p class="videoTitle">Название видео</p>
           <img src="/img/video/1.gif" title="Название видео" alt="Название видео" />
           <p>Здесь описание видео.Небольшое я хз сколько строк может быть.Ещё ещё текста можно добавить.</p>
        </div>      
   </div>
```

Таких блоков будет несколько, даже много, данные будут разные. Интересует появление блока `videoDescr` при наведении на картинку. У `videoDescr` стоит `display: none` в `css`.

Comment: на html бы посмотреть.
Как понять, какой блок какому соответствует?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var videoItem = $('.videoName a img'),
        videoDescr = $('.videoDescr'),
        enter = function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                index = videoItem.index($this);
            $this.fadeTo(200, 0.7);
            videoDescr.eq(index).show().animate({left: 120}, 200);
        },
        leave = function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                index = videoItem.index($this);
            $this.fadeIn(200);
            videoDescr.eq(index).hide();
        };

    videoItem.mouseenter(enter).mouseleave(leave);
});
```

сам не тестил, но по идее должно работать, при условии что классы videoName и videoDescr не выставлены для "левых" элементов

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло ) Чётко ) Как надо )

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать css.
http://jsfiddle.net/kuxzW/embedded/result/